# Ejecución .EXE autónoma y ruta relativa

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy creando una aplicación C# con windows form la idea es ejecutar tres *.EXE* con una ruta relativa, esta aplicación va a ser un ejecutable en un *usb* o *CD* funciona que le entregue una ruta específica y funciona mi parte del código

```
System.Diagnostics.Process spt = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
spt.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
spt.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\Proyecto\i2600 V4.06\drivers\setup.exe";
//spt.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C: \Users\Nicolas\Desktop\Proyecto\i2600 V4.06\drivers\";
spt.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
spt.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
spt.Start();
```

Al no conocer que ruta le entregara el pc no deja poder ejecutar mis *.EXE*, espero poder hacer que éstos se ejecuten en modo silencioso sin que me aparezcan las pantallas de instalación de cada una y sea de forma autónoma

Answer (score 2):

Has probado con:

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string.Format("{0}\\miEjecutable.exe", Application.StartupPath));
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Revise el codigo que me respondieron pero no resuelve mi problema, ya que al darle el nombre de mi .EXE este no lo encuentra en mi PC. Ademas de la ruta de mi ejecutable se encuentra en mi PC pero los otros tres estan en la ruta del USB lo cual dificulta la ejecucion de estos

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process spt = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
spt.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
spt.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"drivers\setup.exe";
//spt.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C: \Users\Nicolas\Desktop\Proyecto\i2600 V4.06\drivers\";
spt.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
spt.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
spt.Start();
```

Con esta linea de codigo obtienes el directorio donde está tu ejecutable, solo tienes que adaptarlo.

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

sl2