# ¿Cómo puedo saber la dirección de un archivo sin importar dónde esté?

Tags: c#, archivo

En mi carpeta de Release debe de estar el ejecutable y el archivo, pero puede que la dirección del archivo sea diferente a la que definí.
Hay algún modo de acceder al archivo sin importar dónde esté?

```
 using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Release\\Release\\Datos.txt"))
```

Comment: esta pregunta te sirve? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25987/324

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso de un OpenFileDialog

```
    OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
    op.FileName = "";
    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(op.FileName))
    }
```